# React Builder tool won't set public url correctly

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to build my react app with react's build tool.

```
npm run build
```

But when I open the index.html file in the build folder, I can't see anything except a blank page. That's because react builder sets script and css paths wrong.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<title>React App</title>
<style>
</style>
<link href="/static/css/main.5fa823c3.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.09bdcb2b.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there is slash before every file path. If I fix this by hand, then the script works but the browser cannot find the "service-worker.js" file because value of the process.env.PUBLIC_URL is null. (service-worker.js exists in the right location)

[image]

```
export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      console.log("URL: "+process.env.PUBLIC_URL) //THIS IS NULL
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(swUrl)
        .then(registration => {
          registration.onupdatefound = () => {
            const installingWorker = registration.installing;
            installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
              if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
                if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                  // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
                  // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
                  // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
                  // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
                  console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
                } else {
                  // At this point, everything has been precached.
                  // It's the perfect time to display a
                  // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
                  console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
                }
              }
            };
          };
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
        });
    });
  }
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Basically, it cannot set the public url.

How can I fix this? There is almost no information about this problem anywhere.

Comment: Which build tool are you referring to? Do you mean CreateReactApp's scripts? If not, build does run fine out of the box there, if you want something to compare with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set your 'homepage' on your package.json file. Assume that your project is in a folder named "project" on the root of your server's working directory.

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "homepage": "/project",
}
```